# increment by one modulo 256

Tags: packet, modulo

I'm trying to send a packet. I've established reliable communication. I received a sequence number of 0x00 from the client. I'm told to increment that sequence number by one modulo 256 and send that in my next serial API header. I'm confused as to what they mean by increment by one modulo 256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply resume, each time you have to send API header :

1. Increment the received sequence number.
2. If the sequence number is then 256, reset it to 0.
3. Send the resulting sequence number with your next serial API header.

To explain the exact meaning of increment 1 modulo 256 :

That means that the expected sequence number should be ( `received sequence number from the client` + 1 ) modulo 256. If you consider the maths, that means that your resulting sequence number should always be a value between 0 and 255  as the modulo 256 of any integer could only be that (for a signed integer between -128 and +127, the modulo operation will give the same binary result, whatever you consider the integer signed or unsigned). So each time the sequence reach 256, it is a restart from 0 :

| Client sequence number | You send |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| .. | .. |
| 254 | 255 |
| 255 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| .. | .. |

As you tell :

> I received a sequence number of 0x00

That implies that the received sequence number is a byte, thus it can only be a positive integer between 0 and 255 (or a signed integer between -128 and +127, but the modulo operation will give the same binary result, whatever you consider the integer signed or unsigned). If the received sequence number isn't just a byte, it could be then any integer in the range of the provided format. In that case, you still have to apply the required formula. Example with a word type client sequence number :

| Client sequence number | You send |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| .. | .. |
| 255 | 0 |
| 256 | 1 |
| 257 | 2 |
| .. | .. |
| 510 | 255 |
| 511 | 0 |
| 512 | 1 |
| .. | .. |
| 4336 | 241 |
| .. | .. |

> I'm told to increment that sequence number by one modulo 256

Means to increment by one and apply a modulo 256 **on the result** to get your sequence number.